# How to write nested if/then statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm supposed to

> define a method, three_digit_format(n), that accepts an integer, n, as an argument. Assume that n < 1000. Your method should return a string version of n, but with leading zeros such that the string is always 3 characters long.

I have been tinkering with versions of the below code, but I always get errors.  Can anyone advise?

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  stringed = n.to_s
  stringed.size
  if stringed.size > 2
    return stringed
  end
  elsif stringed > 1
    return "0" + stringed
  end
  else 
    return "00" + stringed
  end
end
puts three_digit_format(9)
```

Comment: do `'%03d' % n`

Comment: @Matt, this is the best, I think you can write a perfect answer.

Comment: @Matt can you explain your code?

Comment: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)".

Comment: When asking about code you've written it's important to read "[mcve]". "always get errors" makes it mandatory you tell us what the error is.

Comment: "I have been tinkering with versions of the below code, but I always get errors. Can anyone advise?" – Yes: look at the errors and fix them. Since you are not telling us what the errors are, there is nothing we can do for you. Only you know what the errors are, so only you can fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

## `rjust`

You could just use [`rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
n.to_s.rjust(3, '0')
```

> If integer is greater than the length of str, returns a new String of
>   length integer with str right justified and padded with padstr;
>   otherwise, returns str.

## Your code

#### Problem

If you let your text editor indents your code, you can notice there's something wrong:

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  stringed = n.to_s
  stringed.size
  if stringed.size > 2
    return stringed
  end
elsif stringed > 1       # <- elsif shouldn't be here
  return "0" + stringed
end
  else
    return "00" + stringed
  end
end
puts three_digit_format(9)
```

#### Solution

`if`, `elsif` and `else` belong to the same expression : there should only be one `end` at the end of the expression, not for each statement.

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  stringed = n.to_s
  if stringed.size > 2
    return stringed
  elsif stringed.size > 1
    return "0" + stringed
  else
    return "00" + stringed
  end
end
puts three_digit_format(9)
# 009
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  We haven't covered .rjust yet, so I think my instructor wanted me to do something more complicated, but this definitely solves the problem neatly :)

Answer (score 2):

This function, as some have pointed out, is entirely pointless since there's several built-in ways of doing this. Here's the most concise:

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  '%03d' % n
end
```

Exercises that force you to re-invent tools just drive me up the wall. That's not what programming is about. Learning to be an effective programmer means knowing when you have a tool at hand that can do the job, when you need to use several tools in conjunction, or when you have no choice but to make your own tool. Too many programmers jump immediately to writing their own tools and overlook more elegant solutions.

If you're committed to that sort of approach due to academic constraints, why not this?

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  v = n.to_s

  while (v.length < 3)
    v = '0' + v
  end

  v
end
```

Or something like this?

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  (n + 1000).to_s[1,3]
end
```

Where in that case values of the form 0-999 will be rendered as `"1000"`-`"1999"` and you can just trim off the last three characters.

Since these exercises are often absurd, why not take this to the limit of absurdity?

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  loop do
    v = Array.new(3) { (rand(10) + '0'.ord).chr }.join('')

    return v if (v.to_i == n)
  end 
end
```

If you're teaching things about `if` statements and how to append `elsif` clauses, it makes sense to present those in a meaningful context, not something contrived like this. For example:

```
if (customer.exists? and !customer.on_fire?)
  puts('Welcome back!')
elsif (!customer.exists?)
  puts('You look new here, welcome!')
else
  puts('I smell burning.')
end
```

There's so many ways a chain of `if` statements is unavoidable, it's how business logic ends up being implemented. Using them in inappropriate situations is how code ends up ugly and Rubocop or Code Climate give you a failing grade.

Comment: "Exercises that force you to re-invent tools just drive me up the wall. That's not what programming is about." Definitely. Code reuse is SO important and there are so many existing code libraries now that having to reinvent them as an exercise is a waste of time and energy. Knowing how to write a sort algorithm is fine, but knowing where to find one is even better than writing one that is not done well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `rjust` and applying a format `'%03d' % n` are built in ways to do it.

But if you have to stick to what you've learned so far, I wonder if you've been introduced to the `case` statement?

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  case n
  when 0..9
    return "00#{n}"
  when 10..99
    return "0#{n}"
  when 100..999
    return "#{n}"
  end
end
```

I think it's cleaner than successive `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my spin on it:

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  str = n.to_s
  str_len = str.length
  retval = if str_len > 2
             str
           elsif str_len > 1
             '0' + str
           else 
             '00' + str
           end
  retval
end

three_digit_format(1)   # => "001"
three_digit_format(12)  # => "012"
three_digit_format(123) # => "123"
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
def three_digit_format(n)
  str = n.to_s
  str_len = str.length
  if str_len > 2
    str
  elsif str_len > 1
    '0' + str
  else 
    '00' + str
  end
end
```

The way it *should* be done is by taking advantage of String formats:

```
'%03d' % 1   # => "001"
'%03d' % 12  # => "012"
'%03d' % 123 # => "123"
```